# How to make the Doctor Strange reality bend?

Tags: modifiers, effects

I've got this idea, to try and recreate the **Doctor Strange reality bending effect**. With that I mean the one where the floor peels back and twirls on itself.
I thought it would be relatively easy to do, but I've found myself with some problems, I tried to add *loop cuts* to a plane to act as steps, use the *edge split modifier*, then the *solidify*, and lastly the *simple deform*. But it affects the whole mesh so I used a *vertex weigh proximity* modifier, but this one only affects on one point.
Is there a way to do this effect without using drivers and making the scene very over-complicated?
Image of the actual effect for reference[image: Example]

Comment: hello, your picture is very dark and blurry, do you have other references?

Comment: The best reference I can give you is the [actual scene](https://youtu.be/v-G5rpTKE9Q?t=32)

Comment: have you tried the Lattice or the Mesh Deform or Surface Deform modifiers?

Comment: For the stair stpes, using a Array Modifier with Object Offset should do the job. This sprial stair tutorial may help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZDHC_vL_7Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your idea of using the *Simple Deform* modifier seems to work with the *Twist* option and an empty as *Origin* that you move on the X axis. Once your good, parent both the stairs and the empty to a new empty that you rotate 45° on the Y axis:

[image]

[image]

In the clip you show, the stairs don't even seem to bend on their height, they just duplicate the first stairs and delayed a bit the animation, imho it's as simple as that, but you can also deform it a bit with a *Lattice* or a Mesh Deform modifier.

Comment: I think Marvel is very very overestimated. But ok, +1 for the effort ; )

Comment: i think it took them 15 minutes to make this fx  :o

Comment: Yes, c'est des petits bras... ^^

Comment: yes a band of small arms